# FBLoginView not getting user email

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

When I do:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
  [_fbLoginView setReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email"]];
  [_fbLoginView setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
  self.profilePictureView.profileID = user.id;
  self.nameLabel.text = user.name;
}
```

I just get:

```
(lldb) po user
{
    "first_name" = Name;
    gender = female;
    id = 1459547723244130;
    "last_name" = Surname;
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/1459547723244130/";
    locale = "en_US";
    name = "Name Surname";
    timezone = 1;
    "updated_time" = "2014-06-30T08:07:59+0000";
    verified = 1;
}
```

Even when I'm notified that application requires my email address.

How to fetch user email from Facebook using `FBLoginView`?

Comment: Does Graph Explorer show your email address: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cemail&version=v2.0 If not, have a look at your Facebook profile and check whether the email address ends on `@facebook.com`

Comment: The problem is that graph API does NOT show my email address! The thing is that my FB test account didn't have email address confirmed so it wasn't being sent.

Comment: Well, when your test account has no confirmed email, then this can't work. As stated in the docs: `This field will not be returned if no valid email address is available.`

Answer (score 1):

For Check Permission Click [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.2)

[image]

viewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<FBLoginViewDelegate>
```

viewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
    loginView.center = self.view.center;
    loginView.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
    [loginView setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:loginView];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

After successfully login called bellow delegate method

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {

 self.profilePictureView.profileID = user.id;
  self.nameLabel.text = user.name;

}
```